# Harddrive is full of Audio and Photos, how can I find them?

Tags: hard-drive, audio, photos

I have bought a new Macbook and when I go to About This Mac -> Storage I see: 1.11 GB Audio and 750 MB of Photos.. But I have not copied any Audio or Photos to this laptop.

How can I find where these files are? For example in Windows there was this app: WinDirStat https://windirstat.info/ Anything like this for Mac?

Comment: are any of those files in your Pictures folder or Music folder?

Comment: There are no files in those folders.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Daisy Disk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com)? It's a fantastically fluid and feature filled application for the cause.

However, I think the majority of the space taken up by photos are operating system/application assets

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to install third party software (and deal with side effects) you can use the Terminal located in your utility folder.

type `mdfind .mp3` to find mp3 files

repeat for mp4, jpeg, PNG and so on....

Comment: This even finds texts in pdf files!!

Comment: You need to use the (.)mp3 to only show files with mp3 extension.